# What will happen when two similar photons incident on a free metal electron simultaneously?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Will the other photon pass through without getting deflected.What are the other possibilities?.

Comment: Why do you say that the electron can only absorb one photon at a time? Do you have a reference for this affirmation?

Comment: I said base on molecular resonance,sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When multiple photons arrive simultaneously it is the same as if a single photon of the same total energy arrived.  See [multi-photon absorption.](https://www.rp-photonics.com/multiphoton_absorption.html)  This is easy to generate with ultrafast laser pulses, but hard to control.

I have seen references of from two to nine photons absorbed simultaneously, based on spectroscopic results.

Comment: What happens for a free electron,can we do the same process with radio waves?

Comment: why multi photon absorption does't happen for molecular excitation?

Comment: Free electrons can interact with EM waves (and photons), but you generally need very intense sources in order to affect unbound electrons enough to see an effect.  But it is possible, and I have done it in an ultrafast laser lab.

Comment: Then can we dissociate molecules using ultrafast laser without considering the molecular resonance?